# fstrim vs. mount -o discard: How come discard.... doesn't?

Tags: linux, ssd, ext4

I've noticed from time-to-time that running `fstrim` on mounted ext4 filesystems yields massive amounts of trimmed space even when these filesystems are mounted with the `discard` option. I thought the `discard` mount option was supposed to trim ext4 right away. Why does this not seem to be the case? NOTE: `scd1` is on a pass-through disk behind an Areca RAID controller if that makes the difference.

```
# fstrim -v /mnt/cache/
/mnt/cache/: 1351144587264 bytes were trimmed

# mount | grep cache
/dev/sdc1 on /mnt/cache type ext4 (rw,noatime,nodiratime,discard)
```

Comment: To find out why, run `fstrim` twice in succession.

Comment: It is also recommended to not use the `discard` mount option but rather let a `cronjob` do the work or a `systemd-timer` once a week which once Ted T'so [recommended](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.file-systems.ext4/41974).

Comment: Thanks for the link. Had no idea discard was problematic.

Comment: @MichaelHampton - first run: 3658035200 bytes trimmed, second run: 0 bytes trimmed. Seems to make sense. What have I missed?